# Extended real line is 2nd Countable (Clarification).

Tags: general-topology

The extended real line can be given the order topology i.e the topology generated by the basis elements $(a,b)=\{a<x<b\},R_a=\{x>a\}$ and $L_a=\{x<a\}$ where $a,b\in \bar R$.

Hence, a countable basis would just be the above sets except with the restriction that $a,b\in \mathbb Q\cup \{+\infty,-\infty\}$

Comment: Well the real line is second countable? It's just not if you use the lower limit topology. You can check the wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space

Comment: @0CT0 An extension of a second countable space need not always be second countable. So it's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Restricting the base elements to rational endpoints (in all 3 types) gives a countable base, as Q is order dense in the extended reals: for any $a < b$ we can find a rational strictly in-between.

As all order topologies are $T_3$ (even $T_5$) Urysohn's metrication theorem already tells us it's metrisable (which is also obvious if you know that $\bar{\Bbb R}$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1] \subseteq \Bbb R$.)

Comment: Hi just to clarify the points need only come from $\mathbb Q$ and not necessarily $\mathbb Q\cup \{+\infty,-\infty \}$?

Comment: @JhonDoe no $\Bbb Q$ more than suffices.