# Borel $\sigma$-algebra on Extended Real Line.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

In the following post, [Extended real line is 2nd Countable (Clarification).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338239/extended-real-line-is-2nd-countable-clarification?noredirect=1#comment6870609_3338239) it was shown that the extended real line had a countable basis in the forms:  $(a,b)=\{a<x<b\},R_a=\{x>a\}$ and $L_a=\{x<a\}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Q$.

Hence the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on Extended Real Line i.e., $B_{\bar {\mathbb R}}  $ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the basis elements. However, in my notes $B_{\bar {\mathbb R}}=\{E\subseteq \bar R|E\cap \mathbb R\in B_{\mathbb R}\}$.

I can show that $B_{\bar {\mathbb R}}\subseteq \{E\subseteq \bar R|E\cap \mathbb R\in B_{\mathbb R}\}$ because the countable basis elements above when intersected by $\mathbb R$ are open sets in $\mathbb R$, hence are in the Borel Algebra of $\mathbb R$.

But I'm stuck at the other inclusion any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $E \in \{E\subseteq \bar R|E\cap \mathbb R\in B_{\mathbb R}\}$. Then
$$E=(E\cap \mathbb R) \cup (E \cap \{ + \infty, - \infty\})$$
By definition $E\cap \mathbb R$ is Borel.

$E \cap \{ + \infty, - \infty\}$ is Borel because it is a finite set.

Thus their union, i.e. $E$ is Borel.

Comment: By definition $E\cap \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel subset of.... $\mathbb{R}$. The only non-trivial part of the proof is showing that it's also a Borel subset of $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline T$ be the topology on $\overline {\Bbb R}.$ Let $T$ be the topology on $\Bbb R.$

Let $ S=\{u\cap \Bbb R: u\in B_{\overline {\Bbb R}}\}$.

We have $S\supset \{t'\cap \Bbb R: t'\in \overline T\}=T.$

We have $\Bbb R\in \overline T \subset B_{\overline {\Bbb R}},$ so $\Bbb R\in B_{\overline {\Bbb R}}$, so $S\subset B_{\overline {\Bbb R}}.$

Now $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$ with $S\supset T,$ so $S\supset B_{\Bbb R}.$

So $B_{\overline {\Bbb R}}\supset S\supset B_{\Bbb R}.$

Now if $w\subset \{-\infty,\infty\}$ then $w$ is closed in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ so $w\in B_{\overline {\Bbb R}}.$

Therefore $$B_{\overline {\Bbb R}}\supset\{v\cup w: v\in B_{\Bbb R}\land w\subset \{-\infty, \infty\}\}=\{E\subset \overline {\Bbb R}: E\cap \Bbb R\in B_{\Bbb R}\}.$$

Remark: We actually have $S=B_{\Bbb R}.$ If $X$ is any space and if $Y\in B_X$ then $B_Y=\{u\cap Y: u\in B_X\}$ and $B_X=\{a\cup b: a\in B_{(X\setminus Y)}\land b\in B_Y\}.$

Comment: Thank God, finally a REAL proof.